# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepick is not a function in jQuery datetime in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I am not getting the date in textbox by jQuery datetime picker in the place of I am getting error i.e.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepick is not a function

in asp.net while the same code is working fine in HTML. I search many things regarding this error in a search engine as well as Stack Overflow but nothing works.

Here is my code

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.plugin.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.datepick.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            alert();
            $('#birthdate').datepick({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy' });
        });
    </script>

<input type="text" id="birthdate"/>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure the `js/jquery.datepick.js` path is correct? Try using `/js/jquery.datepick.js` to make the path relative to the root folder.

Comment: the path is right.

Comment: I guess it should be $('#birthdate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy' }); ... It's not datepick... it's datepicker.

Comment: Sorry to say but your guess is wrong if I am replace the datepicker then also the same error is showing

Comment: check in browser console for jquery files. Double check that all the plugins are loaded or not

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV OP isn't using jQuery UI, he's using datepick.js, presumably this: http://keith-wood.name/datepick.HTML

Comment: what is this datepick.js? you sure you can call datepick through datepick.js?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gu8n51jz/

```js
$(function() {
 alert();
 $('#inlineDatepicker').datepick({onSelect: showDate});
});

function showDate(date) {
 alert('The date chosen is ' + date);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countdown/2.0.2/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepick/5.1.1/js/jquery.datepick.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="inlineDatepicker" />
```

Try out with CDN link instead of local, then once it's starts working replace CDN link with local downloaded files.

**Local Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>jQuery Datepicker</title>
    <link href="css/jquery.datepick.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countdown/2.0.2/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepick/5.1.1/js/jquery.datepick.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            alert();
            $('#inlineDatepicker').datepick({onSelect: showDate});
        });

        function showDate(date) {
            alert('The date chosen is ' + date);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="inlineDatepicker" />

</body>
```

Comment: @s.k.Soni. Even after using the CDN link you are getting the same error???

Comment: @s.k.Soni  I have shared my local code as well... try that.

Answer (score 0):

If you got error still after adding the JQuery and datetimepicker js than "**RECHECK**" Code ... you must be calling any one of them JS twice in that page.

Try finding in pagesource ...